# How to extract data from node variables to validate user roles on firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

We are adding authentication roles to firebase.
our messaging structure is like this:

```
/users/<userId>/rooms/<roomId>/
```

roomId is custom string which concatenating both users(sender-reciver):

for example:

```
/users/4hkjheqrnv501eltbg1px/rooms/4hkjheqrnv501eltbg1px-638red8osipedem08j1a6/
```

i want to give write access to this room only for usersId's 
4hkjheqrnv501eltbg1px or 638red8osipedem08j1a6  (which the roomId specifing)

How can I actually extract the userId's from the roomId variable and check  if one of them is within the auth object.

I tried it this way but didnt work:

```
"rooms": {
          "$roomId": {
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid.contains($roomId)"
          }
```

so write access will be granted to this room only for auth users 638red8osipedem08j1a6 4hkjheqrnv501eltbg1px

Any ideas how to modify this?

Comment: Just flip it like this: ".write": "auth != null && $roomId.contains(auth.uid)"???

Comment: actually this isnt safe.  coz event if I single substring from this auth it will give writing access. (for example if I just have uId with the first letter '4' it will have write access

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split your room address to array and find if the user id is in the array like:

```
"rooms": {
      "$roomId": {
        ".write": "auth != null && $roomId.split('-').indexOf(auth.uid) > -1"
      }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because user id's can also contain a '-'.

Comment: also: Simulation failed - Line 20: No such method/property 'split'.